# How to customize sample.lua for pandoc

Tags: pandoc

I just tried the sample, https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/data/sample.lua for pandoc and it works.

I seek a little documentation on what I can edit in it?

Is all document parts defined from the lua functions?

I am reading from a latex document and have two tasks i would like to solve if possible.

Can i wrap each section / chapters in latex in a div, and add classes to them?
Can i put a abstract class on the div element that comes from the abstract.

Comment: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates